# Как принимать JSON, чтобы не создавать класс?

Tags: c#, json

Сейчас я принимаю json в консольном приложении вот так:

```
string response = await client.GetStringAsync("weatherforecast/");
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherForecast>>(response);
```

Класс WeatherForecast:

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Что мне делать, например, если я не знаю какие данные получу? Допустим если в json добавил еще и Кельвина, а в классе не добавил. Да и вообще странно это все, как мне кажется, выглядит....

Comment: А как вы пишете программу, когда не знаете что программа должна делать? Странно как-то запрашивать данные, которые вы не знаете ни структуру, ни содержание. Я не знаю, что тут странного, но может быть вам нужно писать программы искусственного интеллекта, которые умеют "сходи туда не знаю куда, возьми то, не знаю что" - в произвольное API, c неизвестной структурой. Обычно, знаете, делается так. Программист читает документацию на API weatherforecast, пишет программу. Если апи меняется - меняют и программу. Если на вход придут неожиданные данные - нотифицируют о случившемся.

Comment: Можно `Dictionary<string, object>` какой-нибудь юзать

Comment: @AK, некоторые api пишутся на всяких nodejs/php. Им ваша статическая типизация до лампочки. И меняется оно от вызова к вызову, программу менять замучаетесь)

Comment: @vp_arth А типизация тут причём? Тот же php разве поймёт, что в json появлось новое поле, при этом поймёт по названию что для этого названия нужно сложить в это поле базы (чуть иному - в соседнюю таблицу), а по этому - вызвать другое апи, а по этому отправить емейл?

Comment: Появилось новое поле и ничего не сломалось. Этого достаточно)

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае можете попробовать считать в [JsonDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonDocument_Parse_System_String_System_Text_Json_JsonDocumentOptions_)

JsonDocument json = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);